# Coordinates 2D transformation to PostGIS desde QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql

This is a three-dimensional shapefile, I checked in ArcGIS, where the shape attribute indicates POINT ZM.

This is the table:

```
fid        0 
shape*     point ZM
atribut1   A
atribut2      B
ESTE      500
NORTE      1000
```

and when exporting to PostGIS from QGIS indicated in the item "CLASS OF SPACE" NULL and the following error:

"Problemas al insertar objetos espaciales del archivo:
D:/gegrafo/BORRARç/COTACACHIa_Merge.shp

La base de datos dio un error mientras ejecutaba esta SQL:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','COTACACHIa_Merge','the_geom',-1,'NULL',2)
El error fue:
ERROR:  Invalid type name - valid ones are:
    POINT, MULTIPOINT,
    LINESTRING, MULTILINESTRING,
    POLYGON, MULTIPOLYGON,
    CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, MULTICURVE,
    CURVEPOLYGON, MULTISURFACE,
    GEOMETRY, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION,
    POINTM, MULTIPOINTM,
    LINESTRINGM, MULTILINESTRINGM,
    POLYGONM, MULTIPOLYGONM,
    CIRCULARSTRINGM, COMPOUNDCURVEM, MULTICURVEM
    CURVEPOLYGONM, MULTISURFACEM,
    or GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONM
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)"
funciÃ³n PL/pgSQL Â«addgeometrycolumnÂ» en la lÃ­nea 4 en sentencia SQL"
```

Comment: puede llegar a más personas con la traducción que usted pregunta sobre traductor Google

Comment: for eg your question will be "When transforming a 3D shape to postgis archico is depliega a mistake, maybe know if QGIS does not support such exports.

thanks

vparra"

Comment: FWIW, I suspect "archico" may be a typo for "archivo," suggesting the OP is referring to an "archived" or old shapefile.  Vic: que exactamente es el error que se ocurre?

Answer (score 1):

I am experienced in postgis but not familiar with Qgis.

in Postgis I think PointZm could be handled with a point4d but it does not seem that you have point4d on your version of postgis.

Anyway the problem seems to be with the export, it looks like the export from Qgis to PostGis does not find a match for pointZM.

A simple trick can be to convert to PointZ or PointM if that is ok for you.

best regards,

Joaquim Muchaxo.

Comment: Thank you very much with GVSIG I have no problem that the file is exported without difficulty apparently the problem is with QGIS